# Кастомизация NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Использую *DrawerLayout* с *NavigationView*. По нажатии на итемы грузятся разные активити.

Ранее вместо *NavigationView* использовал *ListView* с адаптором. И было все шикарно. Но т.к. NavView инструмент более современный и якобы удобный, решил переписать на нем.

Cкладывается впечаттление что *NavView* хорош только для совсем простых дефолтных меню, а когда речь касается кастомизации, лучше юзать *ListView* или *Recycler.* Или я не прав?

Comment: а в чем проблема? если вам проще работать с ListView например и он подходит для ваших целей пожалуйста

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, читал что NavigationView - это Best Practice, а ListView - устаревший подход

Comment: ну ListView да, используйте RecyclerView.  в Целом же все зависит от текущей задачи, и что вы хотите кастомизировать, используя NavView изначально очень многое дает из коробки, учитывает Material и бьет по рукам когда хотите что-то закостылить, но с другой стороны ограничивает в кастомизации, так что выбор за разработчиком.